# django REST: How to serialize objectId( ) in a one to many relationship

Tags: django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I have a mongodb backend with mongoengine - DRF service. I have a very simple scenario of one-to-many relationship:

models:

```
class Photo(Document):
    path = StringField()
    title = StringField()
    owner = ReferenceField('User')



class User(Document):
    first_name = StringField()
    last_name = StringField()
    photos = ListField(ReferenceField(Photo, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE))
```

Now when I access `/api/users/`, I want the user JSON object to contain a `photos` key  that is an array of just the `Photo ObjectIds` and not the entire photo objects. This is my serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    photos = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field="id")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude=()
```

I get the error -

```
ObjectId("...") is not JSON serializable
```

When I replace `slug_field` by `title`, it works fine. Any help would be great!

Also, is this the right way to approach the relationship where I need to document the one-to-many relationship on both `Photo` and `User` models - seems somehow redundant to me.

Comment: Umm. Not sure what I doing wrong here. Could someone please help.

Comment: @Kevin Brown Could you please help me out here. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the slug_field name is the name the field has in the database column. Check the database. A key could have gotten attached "_id" to the name you gave the column in the first place.